# shell script - subtract 1 from hexadecimal mac address and add colons to it

Tags: shell, busybox

1. I have mac address as `'C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AC'` and
2. I want to subtract 1 from its hex values which is `C4B9837FFFAC` so it will become `C4B9837FFFAB`
3. and after this I again want to add colons to make it formatted by colons, like `C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AB`

I have found some solution which does the job for first two steps,

```
#!/bin/sh
mac="C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AC"
machex=$( echo "$mac" | tr -d ':' ) # to remove colons
macdec=$( printf "%d\n" 0xC4B9837FFFAC ) # to convert to decimal
macdec1=$( expr $macdec - 1 ) # to subtract one 
machex1=$( printf "%x\n" $maclandec ) # to convert to hex again 
echo "$machex1"
```

which will output `C4B9837FFFAB`

How can I add colons to make it `C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AB`?

is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: If the last two digits, (e.g. "AC" above), happen to be '00' then `expr` would return '-1', and `printf` would return *ffffffffffffffff*.  An additional `sed 's/.*\(..\)$/\1/'` would remove all but the last two digits of that.

Comment: If the mac address starts with 00 then after putting this all together including the sed command, the first two digits and separator get dropped.  This is because the printf statement which gets from macdec1 to machex1 doesn't include leading zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
machex2=$(echo $machex1 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' )
```

Comment: That leaves behind a trailing colon on my system, *sed* *v4.2.2-7*.  Adding a `.` before the `$` fixes it, i.e.: `sed 's/../&:/g;s/:.$//'`

Answer (score 2):

**bash** shell script:

`machex2=${machex1:0:2}:${machex1:2:2}:${machex1:4:2}:${machex1:6:2}:${machex1:8:2}:${machex1:10:2}`

This will add the ':' after two hex characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`, `sed` and `gforth` to remove the colons, subtract 1, then restore the 
colons:

```
mac="C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AC"
gforth -e 'hex '${mac//:}' 1 - . cr' -e bye | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:.$//'
```

Output:

```
C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AB
```

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX Awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":";$0=ARGV[1];$NF=sprintf("%X",("0x"$NF)-1);print}' C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AC
C4:B9:83:7F:FF:AB
```